# How can I get location of an .aspx file using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm searching my assembly (using `System.Reflection`) for classes that are inherited from a specific class (`System.Web.UI.Page`).

All these inherited classes have pages in my web.

How can I read `.aspx` file path too (relative to web root)?

I know I can read this path from `.pdb` file, however this file does not exists in live server.

**Edit**
   to avoid confusion, here is a sample of my code. doSomeProcess is not exact process. in fact it receives the class itself and analyzes it too. however it is not important for this code sample.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ... {
    public class FixPaths: System.Web.UI.Page {

        void SearhcAssembly(){
            Assembly library = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(library.Location);
            foreach (Type type in library.GetTypes()) {
                if (FileName == type.Module.Name) {
                    if (type.BaseType != null && (type.BaseType.FullName == "System.Web.UI.Page")) {

                        string NameSpace = type.Namespace;
                        string ClassName = type.Name;

                        // -- This need to be changed --
                        string PageUrl = "/" + type.Namespace.ToLower().Replace(".", "/") + "/" + type.Name + ".aspx";
                        // -------------------------------------

                        doSomeProcess(NameSpace, ClassName, PageUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe there's another way to approach this problem.  As it's kind of awkwardly warded and hard to tell what you want exactly.

Comment: That's a nice question, dude. You could use I/O to recursively scan your current directory and look for \*.aspx files. If you follow the convention of class name = file name, then you could match file & class. But *that* would be an awkward solution, I say.

Comment: I'm a developer who writes automation programs. I'm reading an assembly looking for pages inherited from a class. When I'm writing my code these classes are not available. I need to have a list of classes and also their page location to do some process on it.

Comment: @AndreCalil , your solution is one of my problems. some programmers don't put their files in right place (coding conventions of company) so I need to find them and also make a report out of it (test units)

Comment: I don't think reflection and physical disk location are related...

Comment: @DannyChen, you are right, they are not. but I need to somehow relate them :(

Comment: You might consider using [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to see if a class is a subclass of `Page`.  Some projects put a class between `Page` and actual page classes to add commonly used functionality.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, that is what we do too. I included `System.Web.UI.Page` for simplicity of the question. in our real project real class is different and handles page and function security plus custom user templates. however none of these are related to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob, unfortunately this is not a proper solution. However, as far as we discussed on the comments, it may be the nearest we can get to it.

1. By reflection, get all the types at your assembly that inherit from **Page**.
2. Using a recursive I/O search, look for all *.aspx files under your root folder and keep them in a list (so you can retrieve their full path and so on
3. Compare the types you found with the files you fetched. This way you can report Pages (classes) that aren't on the right file and ASPX that aren't on the right place.

I couldn't find a relationship between the type  and it's source file. Furthermore, we are talking about Pages (declared at the assembly) and ASPX files, which aren't related at all.

If anybody has a better solution, I'd like to take a look at it as well.

Regards

Comment: Actually there is a relation between page and classes. this reference is inside header of .aspx file. 

for example a page header of `<%@ Page Inherits="BigApp.Automation.RightPlace" %>` shows that this page is related to class `RightPlace` from `BigApp.Automation` namespace. THanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The page's relative path from the root is in the `AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory` property (on the page). Is that what you are after?

Comment: @BobSort, you could retrieve each class that inherit from Page, instantiate it and look for this property that Michael suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately this only returns the path and not the page name. what I need is, if for example I have a class with namespace `BigApp.Automation` and class name `RightPlace` that resides in `http:/site.com/BigApp/NoobProgrammer/WrongPlace.aspx` my program should return `/BigApp/NoobProgrammer/WrongPlace.aspx` for `PageUrl`.

Comment: What does ToString() give you on a page instance? I think it includes info to allow you to deduce the filename.

Comment: @BobSort, I've been searching "reflection get the source file from type", but without luck. We need to remember that the type is defined at the assembly (dll), not at the ASPX file.

Comment: @AndreCalil, I can't agree with you more. may be I follow your suggestion and find .aspx files then parse their header to find their class and check if that class is inherited from my specific class. you might post your comment as answer and I'll accept it as it is closest answer.